# WPF Keep visible elements and sample texts in them after binding at DesignTime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have two element on my window:

- A `TextBlock`
- A `Button`

I can see the `Button` in `design-time` by this code

```
<Button x:Name="BtnHelp" Content="HELP"/>
```

But i can't see the `Botton` in `design-time` after binding:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnHelp" Content="HELP" Visibility="{Binding Visibility_BtnHelp , Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />
```

---

Also i can see sample text in my `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock Text="Sample Text" />
```

But can't have a sample data in my `TextBlock` in `design-time` after binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Field}" />
```

---

- How can i have fake data and statuses in my elements **just** in `design-time` with a **easy way** after binding??
- Do you suggest a way base on `d:...` property in `XAML` or another way?

Comment: There's multiple ways, depending on how involved you're looking to do it. You can do designtime data to populate your bindings with a designtime datasource specified, you could fiddle with some of your d: options, you could even do something as simple as just setting a `FallbackValue` in your binding base. How far down the rabbit hole do you want to go? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnHelp" Content="HELP" Visibility="{Binding Visibility_BtnHelp , Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Field, FallbackValue='Sample Text'}" />
```

Setting a FallbackValue will also prevent binding errors in the event of a null DataContext so it is good practice.

Comment: FallbackValue is interesting! it works in TEXT property but it dosn't work in VISIBILITY property! I tried it with: true True 'true' 'True' Visible 'Visible'!

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it with one of my bindings. FallbackValue=Visible and FallbackValue=Collapsed work for me.  Don't use the single quotes for those.  I believe the single quotes actually indicates a string array where 'test' would be a 4 element array containing the characters t, e,s, and t.  Updated the answer, apparently the FallbackValue doesn't care about the converter.

Comment: But when i use `Converter` the `FallbackValue` can not help me! my code: `<Button Visibility="{Binding Visibility_BtnHelp , FallbackValue=Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}  }`